# Google Play payments and getting money amount paid by user

Tags: php, android, google-play-services

I am verifying transactions from google play server side (with PHP) by using Google_Service_AndroidPublisher's purchases_products "get" method.
But there is no info about price paid by user for product.
I've tried to google about this matter and found nothing relevant.
Is there any method to know how much user paid when buying specific products.
It is especially important regarding promotional discount codes, when user can reduce total paid price, but i have no knowledge of using discount code for this very transaction.

Is there any other API or method I may be not aware of?

Comment: just calculate depending on google tax from purchases (30% if I'm right). Or store somewhere the discount for the transaction.

Comment: @VladMatvienko: Discount code is being used during payment on google side. I have no knowledge whether payment has been made with discount code or not. There is only notification from google, that it went all ok.

Comment: If you haven't done yet, check the given guidelines in [In-app Promotions](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_promotions.html) wherein there are use cases which you can also implement if you want to support in-app promotions.

See also [In-app Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html) for more information.